# How can i attach my datasource from the database inside a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I`m making a mumbai local train timings project as my class project.. how can i attach my datasource from the database inside a gridview??

```
SqlCommand cmd;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from @d where(Select * from @c where Source = @a AND Destination = @b)",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c",DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b",DropDownList2.SelectedValue);





    //int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //if (i > 0)
    //{
    GridView1.DataSource = //what shud i put here in as a datasource??
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply do some thing like this:

```
con.Open(); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from @d where(Select * from @c where Source = @a AND Destination = @b)",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c",DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b",DropDownList2.SelectedValue);

SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapt.Fill(dt);
GridView GridView1 = new  GridView();
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Then this link might be helpful to you : [The C# Station ADO.NET Tutorial](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson01)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use either `SQlDataReader` or `SqlDataadpter/Dataset`.

```
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        con.Open(); 
      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("yourQuery",con))
       {
           cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from @d where(Select * from @c where Source = @a AND Destination = @b)",con);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c",DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b",DropDownList2.SelectedValue);

          using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
              Dataset dstList= new Dataset ();
              adapter.Fill(dstList);
              GridView1.DataSource = dstList;
             GridView1.DataBind();
            }
       }

    }
```